# SIM card not recognized in Galaxy Tab S

Tags: samsung

I have sent my tablet back to Samsung 3 times.  It is currently back with support.  After the first time, I began to have problems with the SIM card not being read.  It was intermittent in the first few days but then constant.  The device would not recognize that a SIM card was in the device.

I went to Verizon and had the SIM card replaced.  It was fine for  few hours, but then intermittent issues occurred until finally unable to recognize the SIM card.

Samsung could not find any issue for this, sent it back to me but still the problems persists.  I went through the same thing, replaced the SIM, dealt with using the device without the Verizon service I had been paying for, but sent it back.

I received an email from Samsung tech support that they can not find anything wrong with the device. I called in because I do not want the device sent back to me without replacing the SIM slot.  I spoke with one call center employee, he agreed and sent me on to another person.  This person I spoke to insisted that if their tests didn't find anything at fault, they would just send it back to me, doesn't matter how many times I send it in, and suggested I had a virus.

I did some research. I can't find anything on Android viruses that describes the issue I am having.  **Can someone give me some advice on what I might be able to look into in case Samsung does nothing but send my device back?**

Thanks!